# Call with a button a saved number in another page( IONIC, Angular)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

Hi I want to call a number which is saved in another page.
I don't know how to explain this well but I put some captures, and the code that I'm trying to use, I just only want to catch the value of the number and put into the button to call.
I'm using ionic framework and angular. I'm very new at this but I want to create an app and I'm stuck with this.
Sorry for my english is not my native language.
[Client Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtRej.png)

[Call button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRh98.png)

[Button page .ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAiEh.png)

[Detail html page(the first image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybPU2.png)

[button page html (click) function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftrmk.png)

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can create services and then store your PhoneNumber in services.
Check [this](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) out  .I hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you, but I don't know how to put inside of a function the number that is showing in the client detail page to after put in the click function of the button. I just have 1 week working with this, sorry if my explanations are bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ICompanyAddress } from './../interfaces/Map';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedDataService {
  _phoneNumber: string;
  constructor() { }

  get phoneNumber(): string {
    return this._phoneNumber;
  }
  set phoneNumber(newValue: string) {
    this._phoneNumber = newValue;
  }
}
```

Now You could change access its data from any page and changing its value:

example1 (change phoneNumber from a page)

```
  constructor(private sharedDataService : SharedDataService) {
this.changePhoneNumber()

 }

changePhoneNumber(){

this.sharedDataService.phoneNumber = '12345678'

}
```

example1 (get last  phoneNumber changed value in a page)

```
constructor(private sharedDataService : SharedDataService) {
  console.log(this.sharedDataService.phoneNumber)// 12345678

}
```